# Get unresolved text/input from Dialogflow cx entities

Tags: dialogflow-es, chatbot, dialogflow-cx

I am designing a weather bot, which will show different weather details based on a day.

```
if(today) -> "Currently, in New York City, it is mostly cloudy with a 
             high of 65°F and a low of 55°F. There is a 30% chance of rain today."
if(tomorrow) -> "Tomorrow, it is expected to be partly cloudy with a high 
             of 70°F and a low of 60°F. There is a 20% chance of rain."
if(some other day e.g Thursday) -> According to our forecast, it will be 
                 sunny with a high of 75°F and a low of 60°F in Los Angeles on Monday.
```

To implement this feature I am using `@sys.date system entity`.

Is there any way I can extract unresolved/raw text which I can store in a parameter and use in the route conditions to show different answers as mentioned above.

Note: I can very well show diff answers using webhook, but I am trying to implement this without the use of webhooks.

Thanks
Surya

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "unresolved/raw text" which you want to store in parameter ?